# sql database structure advice needed

Tags: tracking, inventory

I have been thinking about designing a database and have come at the point where am not sure what way would be the best way to structure it.

I am trying to track an item move along the supply chain. something like

1. Item scanned in the database with an initial location and final destination with a time stamp
2. Item scanned again with a new location and a time stamp
3. Scanned a few more times until the final location where there is a delivered status along with a time stamp.
4. The customers are each of these destination need to see all items with that final destination with the option of viewing all delivered item, items on the way and both (delivered and on the way)
5. The suppliers need to have the option to sort as above (4) in addition to viewing all locations.

Any suggestions for what would be the best way to make this happen. I am trying to use as few forms as possible but understand that i would need more than one form for different location as I am planning to stick to using a scanner for most of these operations.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: What have you try so far. Can you put the structure that you have in mind and we work it together?

Answer (score -1):

The best answer i can give is to set separate tables in SQL. Simply creat a database with separate tablea correaonding to each timestamp individually.

Once the tables are created, you can then assign a primary key to your timestamps and connect the other tables to separate tables for your customers and suppliers. Allowing all the database tables to be linked to gether.

Comment: So this is what I have in mind so far. table structure 1. OrderNumber 2. Destination 3. Current Location 4. Delivery status 5. Time stamp. The only trouble is I am not sure how I will display each order with only the last entry. If i show all the entries then the table will look messy. thoughts?

Comment: Forgot to mention that each location scan will end up with a new entry and hence I only want the latest entry to show in some cases.

Comment: @JordanD.Angus a table corresponding to each timestamp individually! Come on. That is a dynamic structure database. as timestamp add you add more tables? Immagine you are a delivery service with 1 million delivery everyday. You got how many new tables each day?